# Limit with binomial coefficients

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to compute the following limit (k is a fixed constant):
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ {n/2 - 1\choose(k-1)/2} {n/2 \choose (k-1)/2} }{n-1 \choose k-1} $$

I expanded the binomial coefficient but I got stuck and couldn't get anywhere from there. In theory, if my approach is correct, this should converge to a constant relative to k.

Comment: What is your definition of, say $\binom{3/2}{1/2}$?

Comment: @Dennis: if you look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231212 you will see $k$ is probably intended to be odd.  So perhaps $n$ is supposed to be even.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $n$ is even and $k$ is odd, so the binomial operator still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping only the leading terms in $n$ yields (with $\ell=k-1$)

$$
\frac{(n/2)^{\ell/2}(n/2)^{\ell/2}}{n^\ell}\cdot\frac{\ell!}{(\ell/2)!^2}=2^{-\ell}\binom\ell{\ell/2}\approx\frac1{\sqrt{\pi\ell/2}}\;,
$$

where the estimate on the right is asymptotic for $k\to\infty$.

Comment: $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @Henry: How do you mean? This gives the limit as $n\to\infty$, as desired. I thought that was clear from "keeping only the leading terms in $n$". The numerator and the denominator are polynomials in $n$ of the same degree, so we only need to look at the leading terms.

Comment: @joriki Makes sense.. Thanks a lot